# Symfony 6 - cannot resolve argument

Tags: php, symfony

I've created a class `App\Service\Steam\SteamAPIRepository` and it is listed when I run `bin/console debug:container`. My class constructor looks like this:

```
public function __construct(HttpClientInterface $httpClient, CacheInterface $cache, string $apiKey)
{
    $this->setCache($cache);
    $this->setHttpClient($httpClient);
    $this->setApiKey($apiKey);
    $this->setSteamUrl('http://api.steampowered.com/');
}
```

Before I added the `$apiKey` argument (and just had it hardcoded in the constructor), this was working fine and could be autowired in a controller method for example. I added the API key argument and inside `config/services.yaml` I did the following:

```
parameters:
  steam.apiKey: 'myapikey'

services:
  # after _defaults and App
  App\Service\Steam\SteamAPIRepository\:
    resource: '../src/Service/Steam/SteamAPIRepository.php'
    bind:
      $apiKey: '%steam.apiKey%'
```

But now I see the error:

```
Cannot resolve argument $steamAPIRepository of "App\Controller\App\IndexController::index()": 
Cannot autowire service "App\Service\Steam\SteamAPIRepository": 
argument "$apiKey" of method "__construct()" is type-hinted "string", 
you should configure its value explicitly.
```

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out, I was making quite a simple mistake inside `config/services.yaml`. I replaced:

```
App\Service\Steam\SteamAPIRepository\:
  resource: '../src/Service/Steam/SteamAPIRepository.php'
  bind:
    $apiKey: '%steam.apiKey%'
```

with:

```
App\Service\Steam\SteamAPIRepository:
  arguments:
    $apiKey: '%steam.apiKey%'
```

Now this works as intended